# When is $f(t,W_t)$ an Itô process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Consider a Brownian motion $(W_t)_{t\in[0;T]}$.

If $f\colon [0;T] \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is $C^{1,2}$, we know that $(f(t,W_t))_{t\in[0;T]}$ is an Itô process and we can directly write down the drift and volatility process.

Can we say that it is also an Itô process if $f$ is only uniformly continuous? If not, can we say this at least for weaker assumptions on $f$ (maybe without the possibility to compute the drift and volatility explicitly)?

Comment: Not sure if uniform continuity is sufficient.  That said, a variant of Itô's formula holds for functions that are weakly first differentiable in $t$ and weakly twice differentiable in $x$; see, e.g., https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-0348-9027-4_4

Answer (score 4):

As explained at [Converse of Itô's formula](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435897/converse-of-it%C3%B4s-formula), such a formula would imply that $f$ is $C^2$-differentiable.

> Let $f$, $h$, $g$ be continuous functions and $B$ a real Brownian motion. We suppose that a.s. $$\forall u \in \mathbb{R}_+,f(B_u)=f(B_0)+\int_0^ug(B_r)dB_r+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^uh(B_r)dr.$$
> Prove that $f$ is a $C^2$-function, $f'=g$ and $f''=h$.

In terms of semi-counterexample, the absolute value function is uniformly contiuous but it satisfies a formula that requires the addition of Local time (and so having an Itô formula would imply that local time is zero). [Tanaka's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanaka%27s_formula):

$$|B_t| = \int_0^t \operatorname{sgn}(B_s)\, dB_s + L_t.$$

There are weaker versions that require only convexity e.g. [The Itô–Tanaka–Meyer Formula](https://almostsuremath.com/2020/10/12/the-ito-tanaka-meyer-formula/#:%7E:text=Ito%27s%20lemma%20is%20one%20of,of%20a%20quadratic%20variation%20term.).