# Converse of Itô's formula

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $f,h,g$ be continuous functions and $B$ a real Brownian motion. We suppose that a.s. $$\forall u \in \mathbb{R}_+,f(B_u)=f(B_0)+\int_0^ug(B_r)dB_r+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^uh(B_r)dr.$$

Prove that $f$ is a $C^2$-function, $f'=g$ and $f''=h.$

It seems this is a converse of Itô's formula.

Do you know how to prove it? What is the equivalent of this and the proof when we consider $q$-dimensional Brownian motion?

Comment: OP, do you have a source for this claim? I believe its true and am trying to prove it, but I am curious as to whether this is a conjecture or already known.

Comment: One can cook up a function $f$ such that $\Delta f$ is well-defined and continuous, but $f$ is not $C^2$. Setting $g = \nabla f$ and $h = \Delta f$, we find that the displayed equation in the question is satisfied, but $f$ is not $C^2$.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki This is for the multidimensional case yes?

Comment: @NateRiver: Ah, yes — I did not realise the main question is 1-D, sorry.

Comment: Ah it’s okay, you saved me a lot of effort and grief - I was about to attempt to work on the multidimensional case!

Comment: The analogous dimensional case should be the same but we instead consider $q$ continuous functions $g_1,...,g_q$. In the dimensional version, we need to solve Poisson equation, on a ball (we can always consider the first exit time to obtain this). Is there a way to solve the equation (without boundary conditions)?

Comment: Source of the question (final): https://www.math.ucla.edu/~biskup/275d.1.21f

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete answer. We show $f$ is $C^2$, and then the full result will follow from user479223’s [derivation](https://mathoverflow.net/a/435950). The following idea follows the suggestion of John Dawkins on the [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4590803/converse-of-itos-formula/4592173#4592173), and was also independently suggested to me in private communication by user479223.

Let $K$ be a second anti derivative of $h$, i.e. $K’’ = h$. By Itô’s lemma applied to $K$, and the formula in the problem statement applied to $f$, we have that $f(B_t) - K(B_t)$ is a continuous local martingale.

Since [if a continuous function of a Markov martingale is a martingale, the function has to be affine linear](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406614/if-a-continuous-function-of-a-markov-martingale-is-a-martingale-does-the-functi), we then have that $f - K$ is a affine linear function, that is, of the form $ax + b$, from which it follows that $f$ is $C^2$, and $f’’ = K’’ = h$ as desired.

**An alternate derivation:**

What follows is not strictly necessary, however as the ideas may be relevant for the multidimensional case or in the less smooth case, I chose to write it up. In the following we show “by hand” that $f$ is $C^1$ with $f’ = g$. This may allow us to deduce a converse of Itô’s lemma for less smooth functions.

We show that $f$ is right differentiable, the left differentiability follows the exact same proof by symmetry.

Note that since almost surely, the equality in the problem statement holds for all $t$, we have also

$$f(B_\tau)=f(B_0)+\int_0^\tau g(B_s) \, dB_s +\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\tau h(B_s) \, ds$$

for all stopping times $\tau$.

Now fix arbitrary $x$, and let $\psi = \inf \ \{ t \in \mathbb R \, \vert \, B_t = x\}$. Then $W_t := B_{\psi + t} - B_{\psi}$ is a standard Brownian motion independent of $\mathcal F_\tau$, and we have,

$$f(W_\tau)=f(W_0)+\int_0^\tau g(W_s) \, dW_s +\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\tau h(W_s) \, ds.$$

almost surely for all stopping times $\tau$.

Now for all $h > 0$, set $\tau_h := \inf \, \{t \in \mathbb R \, \vert \, W_t = h \}.$

We then have that

\begin{multline*}
\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} \\
= \frac{f(W_{\tau_h} + x) - f(x)}{h} \\
= \frac{\int_0^{\tau_h} g(W_s + x)\,dW_s}{h} +\frac{1}{2h}\int_0^{\tau_h}h(W_s + x) \, ds.
\end{multline*}

For the first term, we have

\begin{multline*}
\frac{\int_0^{\tau_h} g(W_s + x)\,dW_s}{h} \\
= \frac{\int_0^{\tau_h} g(x) \,dW_s}{h} + o(1) \\
= \frac{g(x)W_{\tau_h}}{h} + o(1) \\
= \frac{g(x) h}{h} + o(1) \\
= g(x) + o(1)
\to g(x).
\end{multline*}

as $h \to 0^+$, where the $o(1)$ notation denotes a term that goes to $0$ in probability as $h \to 0$.

While for the second term, we compute
\begin{multline*}
\frac{1}{2h}\int_0^{\tau_h}h(W_s + x) \, ds \\
= \frac{1}{2h} \int_0^{\tau_h} h(x) \, ds + o(1) \\
= \frac{h(x)}{2} \cdot \frac{\tau_h}{h} + o(1)
\to 0
\end{multline*}
in probability as $h \to 0^+$, where the limit in probability of $\frac{\tau_h}{h}$ can be computed directly to be $0$ from the explicit density of $\tau_h$.

We conclude

$$\lim_{h \to 0+} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} = g(x)$$

and since $x$ was arbitrary, $f' = g$ as desired, and $f$ is $C^1$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer.

If $f\in C^2$ then we have by Itô's lemma on $f$ that for all $u$ a.s. that

$$\int_0^u f'(B_r) dB_r+\frac12\int_0^u f''(B_r) dr=\int_0^u g(B_r) dB_r+\frac12\int_0^u h(B_r) dr.$$

Rearranging yields that for all $u$

$$\int_0^u(f'(B_r)-g(B_r))dB_r=\frac12\int_0^u (h(B_r)-f''(B_r))dr.$$

Taking the quadratic variation on each side yields that for all $u$

$$\int_0^u E(f'(B_r)-g(B_r))^2dr=0,$$

given that $f'$ and $g$ are continuous this implies that $f'(B_r)=g(B_r)$ a.s. Thus we know that for all $u$

$$\int_0^u (h(B_r)-f''(B_r))dr=0,$$

implying that $h(B_r)=f''(B_r)$ a.s.

I suspect that we can prove $f\in C^2$ but I am not sure. I am unable to come up with a counterexample. Thanks for the problem.

Comment: @ThomasKojar How would you do this? You don't have any information on $f(t)$ you just have information on $f(B_t)$.

Comment: Check (I asked on MO since I didn't expect to have an answer): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4590803/converse-of-itos-formula/4592173#4592173

Comment: @ThomasKojar I believe it might be possible. But I was unable to do so.